# Can't run Firefox on Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: firefox, snap, 23.10

On Terminal, when I try to run Firefox, I get this message:

```
Command '/usr/bin/firefox' requires the firefox snap to be installed.
Please install it with:

snap install firefox
```

But it is already installed:

```
[sudo] password for begueradj: 
snap "firefox" is already installed, see 'snap help refresh'
```

More information:

```
begueradj@p50:~$ apt list --installed firefox -a
Listing... Done
firefox/mantic,now 1:1snap1-0ubuntu3 amd64 [installed]
firefox/mozilla 123.0.1~build1 amd64
firefox/mozilla 123.0~build3 amd64
firefox/mozilla 122.0.1~build1 amd64
firefox/mozilla 122.0~build2 amd64
```

**Edit:**

```
which firefox
/usr/local/bin/firefox
```

How to solve this ?

Comment: The path to snap firefox I think is different. `which firefox` should show it.

Comment: Thanks. Edited .

Comment: How did you first install firefox ?

Comment: By snap, but because it did not work, I also installed it by downloading, extracting and installing @SorenA

Comment: Neither snap or apt install Firefox to `/usr/local/bin`. Your various outputs suggest that you have installed Firefox at least three times (snap, apt, another way) without cleaning up between attempts. Solve the likeliest causes by uninstalling the snap and apt packages properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous commentators were right.
As I needed to restore my Firefox snap session, I did this:

```
snap info firefox
```

Output:

```
name:      firefox
summary:   Mozilla Firefox web browser
publisher: Mozilla✓
store-url: https://snapcraft.io/firefox
contact:   https://support.mozilla.org/kb/file-bug-report-or-feature-request-mozilla
license:   unset
description: |
  Firefox is a powerful, extensible web browser with support for modern web
  application technologies.
commands:
  - firefox
  - firefox.geckodriver
snap-id:  3wdHCAVyZEmYsCMFDE9qt92UV8rC8Wdk
tracking: latest/stable
channels:
  latest/stable:    124.0-1      2024-03-19 (3972) 281MB -
  latest/candidate: 124.0-1      2024-03-12 (3972) 281MB -
  latest/beta:      125.0b2-1    2024-03-20 (4022) 283MB -
  latest/edge:      126.0a1      2024-03-21 (4026) 300MB -
  esr/stable:       115.9.0esr-2 2024-03-19 (3988) 256MB -
  esr/candidate:    115.9.0esr-2 2024-03-14 (3988) 256MB -
  esr/beta:         ↑                                    
  esr/edge:         ↑                                    
installed:          121.0.1-1               (3626) 257MB disabled
```

It says that Firefox was disabled. So I [enabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1446697/22-04-firefox-snap-broken-how-to-enable-snap-in-kernel-menuconfig) it with:

```
snap enable firefox
```

After I typed my password, I was able to launch Firefox through Terminal: `firefox`